# All option in choice command

Tags: batch-file, cmd, menu, batch-choice

I am wondering if there is a nice and clean way to add a "select all choices" when building a choice menu in batch.

Currently I have the choice setup as clear item 1, clear item 2, clear item 3 (clear all), exit, and a timeout that the user cannot see.

If I have to I will just re-add all my code to the "clear all" area. I was hoping to see if there was a way to just have the "clear all" use the defined 1 and 2 and then go back to :start like everything else.

***Answer:*** I took Aacini's idea of the "set option" and came up with an even simpler answer. I Changed "`GOTO :start"`to`"GOTO :ClearCache`" for the "Clear All Options". Then I added a "`IF %ERRORLEVEL% neq 3 GOTO :start`" and after that a "`GOTO :ClearCredentials`". This allowed me to keep less lines than the set option and I didn't have to move my code around to have it pass to the next process.

This should allow for multiple but different clear all options for future items.

```
@ECHO OFF
:start
ECHO 1. Clear IE, Chrome, Temp Cache
ECHO 2. Clear Credentials in IE, Chrome, and Windows
ECHO 3. Clear All Options
ECHO 4. Exit
CHOICE /N /C:12345 /T 15 /D 5 /M "Type the number to choose an option."
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==5 GOTO TIMEOUT
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==4 GOTO Exit
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==3 GOTO ClearAllOptions
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==2 GOTO ClearCredentials
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==1 GOTO ClearCache
GOTO :start

:ClearCache
ECHO Clearing Cache...
<code here>
pause
cls
IF %ERRORLEVEL% neq 3 GOTO :start
GOTO :ClearCredentials


REM ===-----------------------

:ClearCredentials
ECHO Clearing Credentials
<code here>
pause
cls
GOTO :start

REM ===-----------------------

:ClearAllOptions
ECHO Clearing All Options...
pause
cls
GOTO :ClearCache
pause

REM ===-----------------------

:Exit
ECHO Exiting...
<code here>
pause
EXIT

REM ===-----------------------

:TIMEOUT
cls
ECHO Exiting because no choices were made in 15 seconds
:END
timeout /t 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very simple way to do that:

```
@ECHO OFF
:start
set option=0

ECHO 1. Clear IE, Chrome, Temp Cache
ECHO 2. Clear Credentials in IE, Chrome, and Windows
ECHO 3. Clear All Options
ECHO 4. Exit
CHOICE /N /C:12345 /T 15 /D 5 /M "Type the number to choose an option."
GOTO Option-%ERRORLEVEL%

:Option-3 ClearAllOptions
ECHO Clearing All Options
set option=3

:Option-1 ClearCache
ECHO Clearing Cache...
<code here>
pause
cls
if %option% neq 3 GOTO :start

REM ===-----------------------

:Option-2 ClearCredentials
ECHO Clearing Credentials
<code here>
pause
cls
GOTO :start

REM ===-----------------------

:Option-4 Exit
ECHO Exiting...
<code here>
pause
EXIT

REM ===-----------------------

:Option-5 TIMEOUT
cls
ECHO Exiting because no choices were made in 15 seconds
:END
timeout /t 5
```